# Regex for *either or both* of last two characters are not digits?

Tags: regex

I can't figure out the proper regular expression for this... Most of my data ends with digits as the last two characters. A subset ends with where either one or both of the last two are non-digits. So xyz99 is normal and I'm able to find those records with `"*[0-9][0-9]$"`. If I change that to `"*[^0-9][^0-9]$"` then I get records where *both* are non-digits.

I don't know regex well enough to match all of the following with a single regex: xy9z, xyz9, xyzw, but not matching xyz99.

I prefer a single regex, but (already know how to and) can work-around with multiple.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `[^0-9].$|[^0-9]$`

Comment: Note also that the `*` in your attempt is wrong, it will either match a literal `*` or produce an error "repetition with nothing to repeat" or similar. The `*` operator means "repeat the previous expression as many times as possible, but allow zero repetitions" but of course at the beginning of a regex, there is no previous expression to repeat. (The regex for "anything" is `.*` where `.` matches any single character, and `*` repeats as many times as possible.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the `*` without a preceding character. You're absolutely right.

Comment: Also, your response of using the "or" `|` is central to what I was missing and suggested below several times. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^\d]$|[^\d].$`

should do the trick

https://regex101.com/r/PsZxLj/2

It matches anything that doesn't end in a digit OR anything where the 2nd to last character isn't a digit.  Lots of ways to do this, but pick one that is easy for you to read and maintain. :)  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. The simplest solution was eluding me!

Comment: @DaveSmith A second set of eyes really makes all the difference! Happy to help :)

Comment: `[^\d]` can usually be simplified to `\D` if your regex dialect supports this notation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
(?:\d[^\d]|[^\d].)$
```

Comment: I think I see where you're going with this and will try maybe a variation of it. Using it exactly didn't work for me and I should add this is inside Oracle SQL. Here is what I tried: `select * from mytable where regexp_like( myfield, '(?:\d[^\d]|[^\d].)$' );` and it returned way too much data.

Comment: This specifically excludes values where both the last characters are digits. It's not clear from your question whether that's an actual requirement; if not, one would expect this to match too little rather than too much (if your regex dialect supports these Perl-style regex extensions in the first place).

Comment: "match all of the following with a single regex: xy9z, xyz9, xyzw, but not matching xyz99." The requirement seems very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative lookahead `(?!...)`.

```
(?![0-9]{2}).{2}$
```

This will first make sure that `[0-9]{2}` (2 digits) does not match. Then proceeds to match the remaining regex, which matches any 2 characters `.{2}` followed by the end of the string `$`.

[image: regex diagram]
<sup>[Regexper](https://regexper.com/#%28%3F!%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%29.%7B2%7D%24)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this. I am inspired to learn about the "lookahead" (and its negative variation).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the quick and helpful responses. A couple of the references above that start with `"(?"` are beyond what I understand so far. But the "or" operator is what I was missing. Here is what I ended up using (and it worked): `select * from mytable where regexp_like( myfield, '.*([^0-9]|[^0-9][0-9])$' );`